# Sensor TYPE_ALL not showing in Android studio

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am pretty new to android programming. I was trying to implement a app which pulls all android sensor values and displays on screen. I referred some online documents and tried writing below.

```
package com.example.my.robuto;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.List;

public class phone_sensor extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_sensor);

        SensorManager sMgr = (SensorManager)this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        //Sensor proximity_sensor = sMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.);
        List<Sensor> list = sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    }
}
```

When i type type the last part sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL) I see TYPE_ALL shows up in RED. Also if i look at options for Sensor. I don't see anything with TYPE_ ! Am i missing something? I selected   API 25: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

It was silly of me to not use: import android.hardware.Sensor;
Once i use it issue is fixed.